# Ice thickness historical dataset around southern Alberta

Tags: weather, canada

I'm looking for a historical ice thickness dataset in southern Alberta (or its vicinity) to confirm test criteria for an electrical substation's equipment. For now, I am using the "Radial Wet Snow
Accretion" 50-years return value from AESO's map (see link below), but it's way conservative, and manufacturers either can't meet it or are reluctant to test for it (and this test is not budgeted).

I have found [these datasets from Environment Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/ice-forecasts-observations/latest-conditions/archive-overview/thickness-data.html) but the one which might be applicable (1947 to 2002) is outdated, the stations don't all have names, and it's hard to correlate them with physical locations. I followed the steps suggested in [this comment](https://open.canada.ca/en/comment/14087#comment-14087) but even with a response, 2002 seems quite outdated.

There's also [this weather map](https://www.aeso.ca/assets/downloads/2011-08-12-Wet-Snow-And-Wind-Loading-Map.pdf) published by the AESO, but it's the result of a statistical calculation for transmission lines, not actual historical data. Plus, as mentioned above, it seems way conservative.

I'll keep looking and will report back if I find something interesting, but any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried asking the coast guard or merchant marine? Mariners would be the only ones with practical interest in this data. Write to them and see if there is anything they have that is declassified. They likely have the best knowledge of what the area is like. Be respectful and clear.

Comment: No luck with the coast guard or merchant marine, their data is taken next to significant bodies of water, not deep in the mainland. Also checked with the NOAA, NASA/RETScreen and could either find no relevant data or data that seemed to correlate with the AESO's, thus we'll go with that (unless a better solution comes up). Thanks.